# What is localContext in MagicalRecord?

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

Sometimes in my app I use MagicalRecord blocks like

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){}];
```

I want to ask, what localContext is? Is it my `[AppDelegate sharedContext]` or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the tutorial on github https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/Docs/Working-with-Managed-Object-Contexts.md

> MagicalRecord provides methods to set up and work with contexts for
>   use in background threads. The background saving operations are
>   inspired by the UIView animation block methods, with a few minor
>   differences:
>
> The block in which you make changes to your entities will never be
>   executed on the main thread. A single NSManagedObjectContext is
>   provided for you within these blocks.